# Storage space running out and I have tried EVERYTHING

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have a cheapo [Wayteq xTab-700qci](http://www.wayteq.hu/node/777) tablet. It just gave me the dreaded

> Storage space running out. Some system functions may not work.

message. I tried every solution that I could find but none of them works. These are the parameters:

Internal storage: 1 GB

- Available: 68 MB
- Apps: 863 MB

  - Google Play Services: 478 MB
  - Google App: 46 MB after deleting data but it automatically grows back to 69 MB
  - Adobe Acrobat, Google Drive, Firefox, FolderSync and iRealPro are the only other apps I have installed besides system apps. All of them take up under 40MB on internal storage because I've moved each to the internal 5.6 GB SD card where it was possible.

I've cleared data and cache for all apps.

The 'System functions may not work' part is true. App updates usually fail because of insufficient space and I'm now getting used to getting 'Google Play Services has stopped' and 'android.process.acore has stopped working' messages right after startup.

What should I do? Is rooting the only solution? Is Android such crap that only by hacking its bowels can I make it usable?

Comment: Disable system apps you don't use. If there were updates for the app the space is freed by disabling the app.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to uninstall Google Play Services. It will be reinstalled (at least it was, for me) when you open the Play Store, but in my case it was only 170 MB after reinstallation, so I reclaimed a lot of space.